# jquery: simple function trigger/call

Tags: jquery, function, triggers, scope

What is the most straightforward method of calling one function inside another?

I have:

```
function carousel_animation(){

            $(carousel).transition({y: m + '=10', queue: false});

            $('article div').promise().done(function(){
                $(this).transition({x:2000}, 500, 'easeInCirc');
            });

            $('article div').promise().done(function(){
                $(this).css({x:'-500'}).transition({x:'0'}, 1500, 'easeInOutQuart');
                $(carousel_reset).css({opacity:0});

                $(carousel_content)
                .css({opacity:100, duration:1500});
            });

};
```

and i need to call it inside this function which is triggered by a click:

```
function carousel_4way (n, el, m) {
        // remove outline from clicked element
        el.blur();

        // animate
        var carousel = '#carousel-4way-nav-' + n
        var carousel_content = '#carousel-4way-' + n
            transitionState  = (transitionState == '-') ? '+' : '-';

        **// I want the function to be placed inside, here**


        transitionState2 = '-';
        transitionState3 = '-';
        transitionState4 = '-';

    };
```

So it's like a very repetitive function that need to use many times in my code. How do i do that?

---

I rewrite the code using Robert Koritnik advice and it's working:

```
function karuzela(n,el,m){  
    var carousel = '#carousel-4way-nav-' + n
    var carousel_content = '#carousel-4way-' + n

    function carousel_4way(){
        el.blur();
            transitionState  = (transitionState == '-') ? '+' : '-';
            $(carousel).transition({y: m + '=10', queue: false});
            };

    function carousel_animation(){

            $('article div').promise().done(function(){
                $(this).transition({x:2000}, 500, 'easeInCirc');
            });
            $('article div').promise().done(function(){
            $(this).css({x:'-500'}).transition({x:'0'}, 1500, 'easeInOutQuart');
            $(carousel_reset).css({opacity:0});
            $(carousel_content)
            .css({opacity:100, duration:1500});
            });

            transitionState2 = '-';
            transitionState3 = '-';
            transitionState4 = '-';

    };
    carousel_4way()
    carousel_animation()
};
```

However, for now i don't see a way to put those 2 nested functions outside and use them on their own like this:

```
function karuzela(n,el,m){
  var carousel = '#carousel-4way-nav-' + n
  var carousel_content = '#carousel-4way-' + n
    carousel_4way()
    carousel_animation()
};
```

Comment: try to learn it from the scratch;http://kangax.github.com/nfe/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just invoke it

```
// I want the function to be placed inside, here
carousel_animation()
```

Comment: that's the exact answer although it seems i had more problems that's why it didn't work for me first time i tried it. anyway thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

### Problem you're having is variable scope

... and their visibility within individual funcitons. Wheny ou're trying to invoke your function, you're likely getting the error that `carousel` and other variables aren't defined.

Try changing your function to have this signature:

```
function carousel_animation(carousel, carousel_content, carousel_reset, m)
{
    ...
}
```

or since you're generating those selectors from other variables just pass those:

```
function carousel_animation(n, el, m)
{
    var carousel = '#carousel-4way-nav-' + n;
    var carousel_content = '#carousel-4way-' + n;
    ...
}
```

This may not be viable for other uses of the same function that we're not aware. But you have to be aware of variable scope. Your `carousel` variable for instance is local to `carousel_4way` function so other functions (if not defined within the same function) won't see it. Hence you have to either:

- put both functions within private function scope and define those variables within the scope so both functions would see then:
- make shared variables global which is not recommended because that opens a completely different *can of worms* as unexpected things may start happening to your variable values

Comment: thank you for your comprehensive explanation! it really helped me to understand the problem. i'm not sure if i should mark it as an answer because it's not the exact question but it was very helpful.

Comment: @dyb: Users usually accept answers that help them solve their problem. These answers may not directly and literally answer their question but rather lead them to solution. It's like teaching hungry people how to grow their own food instead of bringing it to them. I expected that you already knew how to call a function as provided by accepted answer but it was obvious that just calling it wasn't working. So I tried to help you to resolve your problem so calling your function **would work**.